# New run time errors in older code 1004, 424, -2147024809 (80070057)

Tags: vba, excel

Windows 10, Excel 2016  The code is in a Module.

Three years ago, this code worked. Now it throws errors. The text of the error messages is different from that in the other threads with the same error codes.

The code attempts to locate a button and delete it. There is only one button per worksheet.

```
DeleteShapesByCaption "Create a new Schedule of Values tab", wSht

Sub DeleteShapesByCaption( _
    ByVal Caption As String, _
    Optional ByVal WS As Worksheet = Nothing)
    Dim Shp As Shape
    If WS Is Nothing Then Set WS = ActiveSheet
    WS.Unprotect Protect_Password
    For Each Shp In WS.Shapes
        'What kind of shape is it?
        Select Case Shp.Type
        Case msoOLEControlObject
            'May be a commandbutton
            If Shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Caption = Caption Then
                Shp.Delete  'This is where the error occurs
            End If
            Exit For
        Case msoFormControl
            'May be a button
            If Shp.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = Caption Then Shp.Delete
        End Select
    Next
    wSht.Protect Protect_Password
End Sub
```

The error always occur at Shp.Delete

> RTE 404 Object Required
>
> RTE -2147024809 (80070057) The specified value is out of range

Context:

The workbook has a worksheet which is a template. Once the template is filled in, it is copied for month 1. After the month 1 sheet is completed, the create a new sheet button is clicked to create a new sheet for month 2 and the create a new sheet button is supposed to be removed from the month 1 sheet. Each sheet only has one button.

I have used debug.print to confirm that the activesheet is the previous month's sheet.

This code worked properly in 2015. I have modified cell formulae to reflect changes in legislation, but I don't think those changes are relevant because now even the 2015 workbook produces the errors.

The code executes as expected in creating the month 1 sheet. The only difference is that the create a new sheet button is not deleted from the template page.

Comment: Does it error at the first `Shp.Delete` (`If Shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Caption = Caption Then`), or the second one? (`If Shp.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = Caption Then `)

Comment: It errors at the first one. It was originally a single line IF statement. I changed it to a multiline IF in order to isolate the error. The IF condition executes without error.

Comment: @NeilHumphries: did it work in Excel 2013 or Excel 2010?

Comment: I've been enhancing the workbook for about 15 years now. It has worked in Windows XP and later versions and in Excel prior to 2010. I still have 2013 at home. I will confirm whether or not the error occurs in 2013 tonight. I know it didn't occur in 2013 when I was developing the 2015 version of the workbook.

Comment: Did you every delete the temp files when ms had those crazy updates that affected the controls? This happened a couple of yrs ago. Just wondering.

Comment: I'm using a 1 year old laptop, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: When looping over a collection in order to delete some of the members, it's safer to work backwards using `For x = .Count to 1 step -1`

Comment: Just a note: this will exit your loop on the first msoOLEControlObject it finds.  Put the `Exit for` within the IF statement to exit when it finds the object it's looking for.

Comment: In this case, since there is only one button with that caption, it simply exits without wasting time on the rest of the collection. Also in this case, there is only one button at all, but you are right about putting it within the IF statement. It doesn't address the error that keeps happening.

Answer (score 0):

When looping over a collection in order to delete some of the members, it's safer to work backwards:

```
DeleteShapesByCaption "Create a new Schedule of Values tab", wSht

Sub DeleteShapesByCaption( _
    ByVal Caption As String, _
    Optional ByVal WS As Worksheet = Nothing)
    Dim Shp As Shape, i as Long
    If WS Is Nothing Then Set WS = ActiveSheet
    WS.Unprotect Protect_Password

    For i = WS.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1

        Set Shp = WS.Shapes(i)
        'What kind of shape is it?
        Select Case Shp.Type
        Case msoOLEControlObject
            'May be a commandbutton
            If Shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Caption = Caption Then
                Shp.Delete  'This is where the error occurs
            End If
            Exit For
        Case msoFormControl
            'May be a button
            If Shp.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = Caption Then Shp.Delete
        End Select

    Next i

    wSht.Protect Protect_Password
End Sub
```

Comment: While you are correct that it is safer to work from the end rather than the beginning, it didn't solve the problem. I made the changes and get -2147024809 (80070057) error with the msg text The specified value is out of range on the same Shp.Delete line.

Comment: ...and I missed that Exit For in the middle of the loop, so it wouln't make any difference in this case.

Comment: In this case, since there is only one button with that caption, it simply exits without wasting time on the rest of the collection. Also in this case, there is only one button at all.